# Inserting into multiple database tables based on ID field, only first table insert working

Tags: php, ios, mysql, sql, swift

I am pretty new to Swift development and have been following some tutorials to get this far with my API, I am just unsure as to why the second statement is not working with swift when it seems to be working fine in tests with POSTMAN. This works fine when testing on POSTMAN but only inserts into the logIn table, the second insert only works in postman and not in Swift when testing on an emulator
here is the swift code

```
`let URL_USER_REGISTER = "URLString"
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    let date = formatter.string(from: dob.date)
    print(date)
    //send parameters
    let parameters: Parameters=[
        "username":usernameTextField.text!,
        "password":passwordTextField.text!,
        "trainer": trainer,
        "first": firstNameTextField.text!,
        "surname": surnameTextField.text!,
        "email": emailTextField.text!,
        "dob": date,
        "goal": goalTextField.text!,
        "weight": weightTextField.text!,
        "height": heightTextField.text!]

    //Sending http post request
    let headers = [
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ]
    Alamofire.request(URL_USER_REGISTER, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding()).responseJSON
        {
            response in
            //printing response
            print(response)
            //getting the json value from the server
            if let result = response.result.value {

//                    converting it as NSDictionary
                let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary

//                    displaying the message to user
                self.displayMessage(userMessage: (jsonData.value(forKey: "message") as! String?)!)

            }
    }
}`
```

and the php files

```
<?php

//importing required script
require_once '../includes/DbOperation.php';

$response = array();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (!verifyRequiredParams(array('username', 'password', 'trainer',         'first', 'surname', 'email', 'dob', 'goal', 'weight', 'height'))) {
    //getting values
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $trainer = $_POST['trainer'];
    $first = $_POST['first'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $goal = $_POST['goal'];
    $weight = $_POST['weight'];
    $height = $_POST['height'];

    //creating db operation object
    $db = new DbOperation();

    //adding user to database
    $result = $db->createUser($username, $password, $trainer, $first, $surname, $email, $dob, $goal, $weight, $height);

    //making the response accordingly
    if ($result == USER_CREATED) {
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['message'] = 'Your account has been created';
    } elseif ($result == USER_ALREADY_EXIST) {
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = 'User already exist. Please try again';
    } elseif ($result == USER_NOT_CREATED) {
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = 'Sorry, your request could not be processed at this time.';
    }elseif ($result == LOGIN_CREATED_USER_NOT_CREATED){
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = 'LogIn Created, Profile could not be created.';
    }
} else {
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'Please enter all fields';
}
} else {
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'Invalid request';
}

//function to validate the required parameter in request
function verifyRequiredParams($required_fields)
{

//Getting the request parameters
$request_params = $_REQUEST;

//Looping through all the parameters
foreach ($required_fields as $field) {
    //if any requred parameter is missing
    if (!isset($request_params[$field]) || strlen(trim($request_params[$field])) <= 0) {

        //returning true;
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}

echo json_encode($response);


public function getUserByUsername($username)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id, username, trainer FROM LogIn WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $uname, $trainer);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $user = array();
    $user['id'] = $id;
    $user['username'] = $uname;
    $user['trainer'] = $trainer;
    return $user;
}

//Function to create a new user
public function createUser($username, $pass, $trainer, $firstName, $surname, $email, $dob, $goal, $weight, $height)
{
    if (!$this->isUserExist($username)) {
        $password = md5($pass);
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO LogIn (username, password, trainer) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $username, $password, $trainer);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {

            $user = $this->getUserByUsername($username);
            //var_dump($user["id"]);
            $stmt2 = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Client(client_id, client_first_name, client_surname, client_email, client_dob, 
            client_goal, client_weight, client_height, number_of_cancellations)VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 0)");
            $stmt2->bind_param("ssssssss", $user["id"], $firstName, $surname, $email, $dob, $goal, $weight, $height);

            if ($stmt2->execute()){
                return USER_CREATED;
            }else {
                return LOGIN_CREATED_USER_NOT_CREATED;
            }
        } else {
            return USER_NOT_CREATED;
        }
    } else {
        return USER_ALREADY_EXIST;
    }
}


private function isUserExist($username)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM LogIn WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    return $stmt->num_rows > 0;
}
}
```

I have tried looking around and cant seem to find an answer for what I am trying to do. The application is able to communicate fine with the API and in turn with the database as the first insert is working fine. I presume the error is something to do with the parameters being sent from the iOS application as it is working when tested in POSTMAN

Thank you in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: You can take help from here-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310270/not-getting-json-response-using-content-type-application-json-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I have figured out what was going wrong. For some reason the error was to do with

```
            if ($stmt2->execute()){
            return USER_CREATED;
        }else {
            return LOGIN_CREATED_USER_NOT_CREATED;
        }
```

in the PHP file. I have replaced this with

```
                $stmt2->execute();

            return USER_CREATED;
```

and the data is now being added to both tables and not just the LogIn table