# Sending JSON through POST not working - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, post, nsmutableurlrequest

I am sending a JSON string to our server using the POST method. What should happen is that it should return a response showing "Array(JSON String) Array(JSON String)". The response contains two arrays: The first array is populated if I used the POST method, while the second array is populated if I use the GET method. I tried sending the JSON through GET method and indeed, the second array was populated. However, when I tried to send JSON through POST method, both arrays are returned empty.

Here is the code I used:

> NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:sqlArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl/xmlrpc/imwebsrvcjson.php"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:requestData];

NSData *result =[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if (error == nil){
    NSLog(@"The Result string: %@", returnString);   
}
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: @Hot Licks I have no idea actually since the one who can access the server is not around. He just told me that in order for me to tell if the POST is successful, I should receive the response above. :/

Comment: This is similar to 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456966/how-to-send-json-data-in-the-http-request-using-nsurlrequest

Comment: Try it from your browser first, there are REST kits for browsers available.

Answer (score -2):

Here's what I do (please note that the JSON going to my server needs to be a dictionary with one value (another dictionary) for key = question..i.e. {:question => { dictionary } } ):

```
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"StoreNickName"],
  [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier], [dict objectForKey:@"user_question"],     nil];
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"nick_name", @"UDID", @"user_question", nil];
NSDictionary *questionDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:questionDict forKey:@"question"];

NSString *jsonRequest = [jsonDict JSONRepresentation];

NSLog(@"jsonRequest is %@", jsonRequest);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://xxxxxxx.com/questions"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];


NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (connection) {
 receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
The receivedData is then handled by:

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [jsonString JSONValue];
NSDictionary *question = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"question"];
```

This isn't 100% clear and will take some re-reading, but everything should be here to get you started. And from what I can tell, this is asynchronous. My UI is not locked up while these calls are made. Hope that helps.

Comment: Please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable.