# How to send data in url to server?

Tags: ios, json

```
http://novatoresols.com/demos/blow/users/add.json?json={"email":"ali"}
```

How can I send a `key` and `data` to web? Here "**email**" is the `key` and "**ali**" is the value in URL.

Code:

```
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[hostURL stringByAppendingFormat:@"users/add.json?json="]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSString * params =@"{\"email\":\"Ali\"}";

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    // This is how we set header fields
   [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: If you are using POST, you should send your data in the body of the request. You could use setHTTPBody: of the request object to do this. Are you sending xml or JSON? You set the Content-Type to "application/xml", but are trying to send JSON-data?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4466899/1262634 it has your ansewr.

Comment: yes i have changed to application/json but still not working

Comment: also checked the link and done the same as in link but still not successful

Comment: This all depends on what the requirements of your server actually are. Can you give us more details about it, please

Answer (score 1):

Simply Try with this :

```
 NSString * params =@"{\"email\":\"Ali\"}";
 NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[hostURL stringByAppendingFormat:@"users/add.json?json=%@",params]];


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog (@"%@",data);
```

Comment: This won't work, since you are not setting the corresponding content type header. If the content type header is not set, a server treats the body of a HTTP/1.1 message as `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: @Ali : Sorry , I didn't read properly . Check my edited Answer

Comment: @KumarKl tried that too but not working have u checked that link  http://novatoresols.com/demos/blow/users/add.json?json={"email":"ali"}  it send a response but in the response i get name = "The request has been black-holed";
    url = "/demos/blow/users/add.json";

Comment: Yes, I had Checked ... what i getting is **{response: false};** Without Knowing the structure of add.json. Can't decide