# Unable to POST data to Google End Point from Cococa Application (Objective-C). How to do it?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-app-engine-python

I have created an Email utility with the help of Google Endpoints (Python). 
The problem is that I am not able to POST data to it. I am getting an error.

> {  "error": {   "errors": [    {
>       "domain": "global",
>       "reason": "parseError",
>       "message": "This API does not support parsing form-encoded input."    }   ],   "code": 400,   "message": "This API does not support parsing
>   form-encoded input."  } }

What I am doing in Objective-C is given below

```
//Here my URL
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];


//create the Method "GET" or "POST"
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//Pass The String to server
NSString *dataPost = @"{\"body\": \"email body\",\"subject\": \"email subject\"}";

//Check The Value what we passed
NSLog(@"the data Details is =%@", dataPost);

//Convert the String to Data
NSData *data1 = [dataPost dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//Apply the data to the body
[request setHTTPBody:data1];

//Create the response and Error
NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *response;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

//This is for Response
NSLog(@"got response==%@", resSrt);
if(resSrt)
{
    NSLog(@"got response");
    /* ViewController *view =[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:NULL];
     [self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];*/
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"faield to connect");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see: [How to send json data in the Http request using NSURLRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456966/how-to-send-json-data-in-the-http-request-using-nsurlrequest)

Basically, you need to set the "Content-Type" header so that the receiving endpoint doesn't think it's form encoded (the default) and instead recognizes it as JSON.

```
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Comment: its working fine with this data @"{\"body\": \"test\",\"subject\": \"test\"}"

but it is not working with this type of data {"body": "body

First Name Paul A Alabisi
Last Name 
Customer ID 31877
Serail Key 2512948ead29a82d","subject": "sub"}